# How to connect to another server that is not public

Tags: php, server

I have a server with a web application working. These days I have implemented a CAS server in another server that is local. It's running correcly and, that's obviously, I can connect to web application usgin the domain while I'm connected on local network.

I have migrated the pages that manage the login, portal, etc... but CAS has to be in the same place.

The login form is something like that:

```
<form method="POST" action="XXX.XX.X.XX:8443/cas/login" >
    <input type="text" name="username">
    <input type="password" name="password">
    <input name="submitted" type="submit" value="Login">
</form>
```

(I have reduced the code, just for show you the important thing)

I have the login, portal, etc.. in a server whose domain is, for example https://myserver.com and login try to connect with local server but browser try to go to this webpage.

How can I send POST of this form trying to connect with local server independently from where I'm connecting?

In conclusion, I need to connect a public server with local server just to get some information. The same way as mysql_connect(..) of PHP but doing a POST request. If I can do with PHP better, but if there are some solutions in another languages no problem.

Thanks!

Comment: `The same way as mysql_connect(..)` I hope you meant `mysqli_connect()` as the `mysql_` functions are deprecated, unsafe and not been maintained for about 10 years. Please switch over to PDO or MySQLi....

Comment: Yes, but it's not the question. The question is how can I send this form's variables to the local server and later it can give me an answer. Local server is only accesible if you are connected in the local network